# Matrices multiplication yielding the se matrix

Tags: sequences-and-series

I came to know that if there are two Matrices which on multiplication yield a null matrix then they need not be null matrices themselves.

But what if$$ AB=B$$? Is it necessary that matrix  A is an identity matrix.  If not can we prove it without using any trivial example?

Answer (score 1):

$AB=B$ implies $A=\mathrm{Id}$ only when $B$ has full rank (i.e., it represents a surjective linear map). The most extreme counterexample is the case when $B=0$.

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply $B$ on the left by the matrix

```
0 1
1 0
```

you switch the rows of $B$. If the two rows of $B$ are the same, then you get $B$ again.